# Structuring documentation when using Doxygen

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

I am starting to document my PHP5 framework using Doxygen. I am trying to use CodeIgniter framework's inline documentation as a reference. However, its documentation is written using phpDocumentor syntax. Below is an example of CodeIgniter's Loader class description:

```
/**
 * Loader Class
 *
 * Loads views and files
 *
 * @package          CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage       Libraries
 * @author           ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @category         Loader
 * @link             http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html
 */
class CI_Loader {
...
}
```

How can I implement the same structure (Package->Subpackage->Category->Class) using Doxygen? I would like to have a corresponding description page for each element of the structure.

Another one question is how do you structure your project's documentation?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running PHP 5.3 then Doxygen supports namespaces. If you put them in then your documentation will be structured in a similar style to the phpDocumentor's packages. Have a look at the following links for more information about PHP namespaces:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/